# Rails Fetch record from instagram using cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, instagram-api, cron-task

I am using [instagram gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) and I need to fetch users media from instagram
using users instagram id. I already have instagram user id into users table.
I have a few questions

1. Does Instagram gem give any method which pass user id and fetch users media?
2. How can I fetch users media using cron job and any gem do that?
3. How can we authorize cron job that not require login into instagram?

Comment: Please paste the link to your gem

Comment: Here is my gem > > gem 'instagram'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can fetch users media if we have his instagram id and just pass app client_id in request method